# How to use std::generate

Tags: c++, algorithm

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate

states that it takes Parameters

> ```
> ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Generator g
> ```

and the description is

> Assigns each element in range [first, last] a value generated by the given function object g.

so I declared an Array (std::array) with X Elements, where

```
std::generate(&Arr[0],&Arr[X],[](){...})
```

caused a out of bounds violation.
While `std::generate(&Arr[0],&Arr[X-1],[](){...})`  does not.
Note: in a small test program I see that `std::generate(&Arr[0],&Arr[X-1],[](){...})` does not initialize the last element

Next I tried to improve with

```
std::generate(&Arr.front(),&Arr.back(),[&gen](){
```

Note: same effect here: the last Element is not initialized

but in the Internet you also see

```
std::generate(Arr.begin(),Arr.end(),[&gen](){
```

Which compiles fine (and seems to work correctly with initializing the last element)

Now I wonder how `Arr.end()` and in range [first, last) match, as `end()` is an Iterator to first out of bounds element, or where I am doing wrong?

Comment: arrays indexes start at 0 and go up to 1 before the length

Comment: What is `Arr` (exactly, the exact type), and what is the actual error (please copy-paste the error text, don't just describe it, alongside any warnings)

Comment: if `end` is one past then last element of the range the the rang `[begin, end)` is `[begin, end() - 1]`

Comment: Not obvious why your first attempt failed. There's lots of information missing here, so you aren't getting the best possible advice. I guess the 'Array` is not an array, but a std::vector or std::array.

Comment: @john `&Arr[X]` has undefined behaviour

Comment: @Caleth That depends on how `Arr` is declared, which is not specified in the question as far as I can see.

Comment: @john "an Array with X Elements". It is undefined for both `int Arr[X];` or `std::array<int, X> Arr;`

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes,... I am beyond that :-) Thx

Comment: @john, yes its std::array...

Comment: @Caleth Yes, I stand corrected.

Comment: This should be: `std::generate(std::begin(Arr), std::end(Arr), []{ .... });`, or from c++20: `std::ranges::generate(Arr, []{ .... });`.

Comment: Anyway I think you should provide [mcve] so we are sure you have c-array or pointer or whatever, since then it may look a bit different.

Comment: You misquoted the cppreference page. It says the output range is `[first, last)`, not `[first, last]` as you quoted. That means that `last` is not included in the range.

Comment: Example Code: https://godbolt.org/z/zvT8rGeoK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to form a pointer one past the end of an array, but not dereference it.

For raw arrays, `&Arr[X]` is defined to be equivalent to `&*(Arr + X)`, i.e. you first dereference, then take the address. Containers define `[]` in terms of a (hidden) raw array.

Similarly `begin()` and `end()` will be something like `return Arr;` and `return Arr + size;` respectively.

Comment: thats all correct, but I do not understand why .end() is a valid input to ForwardIt last, as end() by default does not give access to an Iterator to the last element...

Comment: @schnedan C++ algorithms take half-open ranges, you pass an iterator past the last element you want.

Comment: @schnedan the algorithms in the standard library all expect a range of `[iterator_to_first_value, iterator_to_element_after_last_value]` and the run over the elements `[first, last - 1]`

Comment: hmm, I am used to the '[iterator_to_first_value, iterator_to_element_after_last_value]' definition but I was not able to translate the term "Last" to this... to me the wording is suboptimal

Comment: @schnedan There's different brackets: `[first, last)` includes (square bracket) the element at `first`, and excludes (round bracket) the (hypothetical) element at `last`. That lets you write things like `void merge_sort(T* first, T* last) { mid = std::midpoint(first, last); merge_sort(first, mid); merge_sort(mid, last); std::inplace_merge(first, mid, last); }`

Comment: Ok, not noticed the different brackets... is there a description on cppreference for that syntax?

Comment: @schnedan I can't find a page in cppreference for it, but it's the [mathematical notation for intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology)

Comment: @Caleth Thx... never heard of that. interessting